# Spring boot @Transactional crea una vez y luego actualiza

Tags: spring, spring-boot, update, transact-sql

por mi cuenta estoy desarrollando una aplicación a modo de práctica. Lo que estoy intentando es con la anotación `@Transactional` un método que me inserte una venta y que con el id que devuelve ese insert, recorro una lista de detalles de un pedido para usarlos como detalles de la venta ya que es lo mismo.

El flujo que necesito es: 
1) Insertar la venta y obtener el id
2) Recorrer una lista de detalles y con cada uno de esos detalles crear un detalle de venta relacionada al id de la venta

Mi problema es que primero me inserta bien la venta, luego recorro bien el detalle de pedido, pero al momento de insertar mi detalle de venta solo lo hace una vez y las siguientes veces hace un update y no un create.

Este es mi método para realizar el flujo:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public Venta create(Venta obj) {

    List<PedidoDetalle> pedidoDetalles;
    Venta venta = objDao.save(obj);
    VentaDetalle ventaDetalle = new VentaDetalle();

    pedidoDetalles = detalleService.getIdPedido(obj.getPedido().getId());

    for (PedidoDetalle detalle : pedidoDetalles) {
        ventaDetalle.setPedidoDetalle(detalle);
        ventaDetalle.setVenta(venta);
        System.out.println("id del detalle: "+detalle.getId());
        ventaDetalleService.create(ventaDetalle);
    }
    return venta;
}
```

Puse un `System.out.print("id del detalle: "+detalle.getId())` para ver si la lista se recorre bien y sí lo hace.

```
id del detalle: 42
id del detalle: 43
id del detalle: 44
```

Esto es lo que obtengo en consola:

1) Insert exitoso de la venta

```
insert into ventas (created_at, updated_at, pedido_id, total) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

2) Insert exitoso del detalle de la venta obteniendo el detalle de la lista

```
insert into ventas_detalles (pedido_detalle_id, venta_id) values (?, ?)
```

3) Las siguientes veces en vez de volver a hacer un insert hace un update

```
update ventas_detalles set pedido_detalle_id=?, venta_id=? where id=?
```

Entonces, ¿qué hago mal para que en cada vuelta del ciclo for se cree un nuevo detalle y no haga una actualización?

Comment: Por favor no le coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, con amrcar tu solución como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema era que estaba creando un objeto `VentaDetalle ventaDetalle = new VentaDetalle();` fuera del ciclo for, por lo tanto, tenía la misma clave primaria(id) y hacía la actualización. La solución obvia fue mover la creación del objeto dentro del ciclo for de esta forma:

```
for (PedidoDetalle detalle : pedidoDetalles) {
        VentaDetalle ventaDetalle = new VentaDetalle();
        ventaDetalle.setPedidoDetalle(detalle);
        ventaDetalle.setVenta(venta);
        System.out.println("id del detalle: "+detalle.getId());
        ventaDetalleService.create(ventaDetalle);
    }
```